# Undefined when trying to parse JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to parse a JSON response with JQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'test.php',
                type : 'GET',
                data : {
                    name : "Peter",
                },
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    alert(response.name)
                },
                error : function() {
                    console.log("error")
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to get the name into the alert box, but everything I get is an `undefined`.

This is the result in the console:

```
Object {results: Array[1]}
   results: Array[1]
      0: Object
         id: "4"
         name: "Peter"
```

When I do `alert(JSON.stringify(response));` I get `{"results":[{"id":"4","name":"Peter"}]}`, so there is definitely valid JSON.

Comment: `reponse.results[0].name`

Comment: How come such a question can get an _upvote_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `response` there is not property `name`. `name` there is in in first element in `results` array, so to get name you need do

```
console.log(response.results[0].name)
```

Answer (score 2):

response is an object which contains an array in results, you need to iterate over ressponse.results or if you're sure it well have only one element, use response.results[0].name

Answer (score 0):

The JSON data contains an array, so you need use an index:

```js
var data = {"results":[{"id":"4","name":"Peter"}]}
document.write(data.results[0].name)
```